# How to determine if a list is an alist

Tags: common-lisp

Is there a simple way to determine if a list is actually an alist ?

My first attempt:

```
(defun alistp (list)
    (and (listp list)
         (every (lambda (c)
                    (and (consp c)
                         (or (atom (cdr c))
                             (null (cddr c))))))
                list)))
```

Returns T for `(alistp '((1 . 2) (2 . 3)))`

But NIL for `(alistp '((1 . (4 5 6))))`

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, let's look at the [definition](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_a.htm#association_list) of association lists:

> association list n. a list of conses representing an association of
>   keys with values, where the car of each cons is the key and the cdr is
>   the value associated with that key.

Given that, this would be a possible implementation of `alistp`:

```
(defun alistp (alist)
  (and (listp alist)           ; a list
       (every #'consp alist))) ; of conses
```

Now, from your code example I can tell that you'd have probably been able to implement this yourself, but you seem to have a different definition of alist in mind. I assume the examples of alists you've seen all looked more or less like this: `((a . x) (b . y))`, maybe `((a . x) (b . (y z)))` But a dotted list with a list as its last element is just – a list, and from your example input it's clear that you want to allow lists as values. (Why wouldn't you, anyway?)

What you have to realize, I suppose, is that your example input `((1 . (4 5 6)))` is *exactly the same* as `((1 4 5 6))`, which is how I mostly see alists with lists as their values used in code – at least, it is how I usually write them.

Now, you also seem to want to exclude `nil` values, although they're lists, too – just empty ones `()`. So, the definition you actually have in mind is rather something like this:

> association list n. a list of cons cells representing an association of
>   keys with non-nil values, where the car of each cons is the key and the cdr is
>   the value associated with that key.

If that is really what you want, follow the new definition:

```
(defun alistp (alist)
  (flet ((true-cdr-p (element)
           (and (consp element)        ; cons cell
                (cdr element))))       ; with non-nil cdr (i.e. value) 
    (and (listp alist)                 ; a list
         (every #'true-cdr-p alist)))) ; of cons cells with non-nil cdr
```

Or something like that. I suggest sticking with the simple version above, though.

Comment: Thanks @danlei. I knew I was missing something obvious... and I was!

Comment: cool answer! but shouldn't the first arg to the and-clause use (consp alist)? Otherwise nil would be considered a valid alist.

Comment: @upgrd Indeed, it is.